# Necessary to link libraries with AdMob & Firebase?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, admob

I'm currently adding AdMob banner ads to an iOS app. 
I was following some tutorials online that explained that it was necessary to "Link Binary With Libraries" by adding the following frameworks.

> The SDK library references the following iOS development frameworks
>   which may not already be part of your project:
>
> -AdSupport
>   -AudioToolbox
>   -AVFoundation
>   -CoreGraphics
>   -CoreTelephony
>   -EventKit
>   -EventKitUI
>   -MessageUI
>   -StoreKit
>   -SystemConfiguration

However on Google's current [Get Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start) AdMob page there is no mention of the linking of these frameworks. Does this mean that this step can now be ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, yes, you can ignore that step. If you're importing the Google Mobile Ads SDK as a framework, it should handle the dependencies for you.

On a related note, if you're comfortable using Cocoapods for dependency management, there's an iOS screencast [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qCxo0D-Sak) that will walk you through setting up AdMob with Firebase in your app.